# Какая максимальная вложенность конфиг файла, с которой может работать компонент Config?

Tags: php, массивы, config

```
<?php



$GLOBALS['config'] = [
    'mysql' => [
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'test'
    ]
];


class Config {
    public static function get($path = null) {
        if($path) {
            $config = $GLOBALS['config'];
            $path = explode('.' , $path);

            foreach ($path as $item) {
                if (isset($config[$item])) {
                    $config = $config[$item];
                }
            }
            return $config;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Какая максимальная вложенность конфиг файла, с которой может работать компонент Config?
В книге был такой вопрос. Но я не понял суть вопроса?

Comment: О каких конфигах идёт речь? Уточните свой вопрос, или добавьте нужный тег

Comment: $GLOBALS['config'] = [
    'mysql' => [
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'test'
    ]
];


class Config {
    public static function get($path = null) {
        if($path) {
            $config = $GLOBALS['config'];
            $path = explode('.' , $path);

            foreach ($path as $item) {
                if (isset($config[$item])) {
                    $config = $config[$item];
                }
            }
            return $config;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

Comment: Я имею в виду, уточните что это за фреймворк, cms или что это вообще? Обычный массив в любом языке программирования не имеет ограничений вложенности

Answer (score 0):

*Но я не понял суть вопроса?*
Здесь о говорится о том, что когда вы используете статичный метод

```
$user_name = Config::get('mysql.username');
```

Вас спрашивают до какой глубины вложенности элементов может достучаться `Config::get()` или другими словами сколько точек можно указать в значении аргумента функции в качестве разделителя уровней вложенности.

Ответом на этот вопрос - сколь угодно, потому как циклом мы проходимся массиву (в нашем примере это `['mysql','username']`) и обращаемся сперва к $GLOBALS['config']['mysql'] , а на второй итерации цикла - обращаемся к $GLOBALS['config']['mysql']['username'].

Этот пример является надуманным и по факту является говнокодом, так как в метод встроена глобальная переменная, а значит есть способ перезатереть её значения.

Что бы не перезатерать настройки - не используют глобальные переменные, а используют глобальные константы. Что бы код был гибким - глобальные константы не зашивают  внутри методов, а передают в качестве аргументов. Пример:

```
<?php
        //Enter your code here, enjoy!

define("CONFIG", [
    'mysql' => [
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'test'
    ]
]);


class Config {
    public static function get($path = null , $config)
    {
        if($path) {
            $path = explode('.' , $path);
            foreach ($path as $item) {
                if (isset($config[$item])) {
                    $config = $config[$item];
                }
            }
            return $config;
        }
        eror_log('invalid request');
    }
}

echo Config::get('mysql.host',CONFIG);
```

Опять же на лицо неразумное использование ресурсов компьютера - так как пример не имеет отношения к реальности. Эффективнее всего напрямую обращаться к элемену:

```
echo CONFIG['mysql']['username'];
```

Также хочу обратить ваше внимание на то что в примере не указана строгая типизация - функция должна возвращать один тип данных. В данном случае статический метод может отдавать массив(если указано неверно имя свойства), строку (если указано все верно) и булев тип false если не указан первый аргумент.

По этой причине не рекомендую изучать Вами данную книгу. Читать говнокод не зная этого плохая практика обучения.

Эта функция заменяется выражением

```
$user_name = CONFIG['mysql']['username']??null;
```